# Options for web scraping - C++ version only

Tags: c++, screen-scraping

I'm looking for a good C++ library for web scraping.
It **has to** be C/C++ and **nothing** else so please do not direct me to [Options for HTML scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping) or other SO questions/answers where C++ is not even mentioned.

Comment: is converting the HTML to XML first an option? there aren't many good HTML parsers for C++ out there, there are for XML however.

Answer (score 57):

- **[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se)** to download the html file
- **[libtidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/)** to convert to valid xml
- **[libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)** to parse/navigate the xml

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was looking for, I have used curl a lot from the cli but I never thought of using it as a library :)

Comment: You can skip step 2, as libxml is able to handle HTML.

Comment: @el.pescado According to [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/issues/211), it would seem that libxml does not support HTML5, only HTML4, so you would likely still have to convert it to xml

Answer (score 8):

Use myhtml C/C++ parser [here](https://github.com/lexborisov/myhtml); dead simple, *very* fast. No dependencies except C99. And has CSS selectors built in (example [here](https://github.com/lexborisov/mycss/blob/master/examples/selectors_low_level.c))

Answer (score 4):

I recommend Qt5.6.2, this powerful library offer us

1. High level, intuitive, asynchronous network api like QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkReply, QNetworkProxy etc
2. Powerful regex class like QRegularExpression
3. Decent web engine like QtWebEngine
4. Robust, mature gui like QWidgets
5. Most of the Qt5 api are well designed, signal and slot make writing asynchronous codes become much easier too
6. Great unicode support
7. Feature rich file system library. Whether create, remove, rename or find standard path to save files is piece of cake in Qt5
8. Asynchronous api of QNetworkAccessManager make it easy to spawn many download request at once
9. Cross major desktop platforms, windows, mac os and linux, write once compiled anywhere, one code bases only.
10. Easy to deploy on windows and mac(linux?maybe linuxdeployqt can save us tons of troubles)
11. Easy to install on windows, mac and linux
12. And so on

I already wrote an image scraper apps by Qt5, this app can scrape almost every image searched by Google, Bing and Yahoo.

To know more details about it, please visit [my github project](https://github.com/stereomatchingkiss/QImageScraper/blob/master/README.md).
I wrote down high level overview about how to scrape data by Qt5 on 
my blogs(it is too long to post at stack overflow).

- [Download Bing images by Qt5](http://qtandopencv.blogspot.my/2017/05/scrape-bing-images-by-qwebengine.html)
- [Create a better images downloader(Google, Bing and Yahoo) by Qt5](http://qtandopencv.blogspot.my/2017/05/create-better-images-downloadergoogle.html)

Comment: Why do you recommend version 5.6.2 and not the latest one (currently it's 5.9.0)?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Main reason is I do not know how stable Qt5.9.0 is, another reason is Qt5.6.2 support windows xp

Comment: Hi currently getting my feet wet in C++, but to my knowledge Qt only does half of the job and you still need a decent and forgiving Html parser (Let's suppose we don't want to  load every page in `qwebengineview` and use javascript engine to scrpae the webpage). Anyway this answrer deserve an upvote specially when you need the scraped data to be presented in a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
// download winhttpclient.h
// --------------------------------
#include <winhttp\WinHttpClient.h>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char byte;
#define foreach         BOOST_FOREACH
#define reverse_foreach BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH

bool substrexvealue(const std::wstring& html,const std::string& tg1,const std::string& tg2,std::string& value, long& next) {
    long p1,p2;
    std::wstring wtmp;
    std::wstring wtg1(tg1.begin(),tg1.end());
    std::wstring wtg2(tg2.begin(),tg2.end());

    p1=html.find(wtg1,next);
    if(p1!=std::wstring::npos) {
        p2=html.find(wtg2,next);
        if(p2!=std::wstring::npos) {
            p1+=wtg1.size();
            wtmp=html.substr(p1,p2-p1-1);
            value=std::string(wtmp.begin(),wtmp.end());
            boost::trim(value);
            next=p1+1;
        }
    }
    return p1!=std::wstring::npos;
}
bool extractvalue(const std::wstring& html,const std::string& tag,std::string& value, long& next) {
    long p1,p2,p3;
    std::wstring wtmp;
    std::wstring wtag(tag.begin(),tag.end());

    p1=html.find(wtag,next);
    if(p1!=std::wstring::npos) {
        p2=html.find(L">",p1+wtag.size()-1);
        p3=html.find(L"<",p2+1);
        wtmp=html.substr(p2+1,p3-p2-1);
        value=std::string(wtmp.begin(),wtmp.end());
        boost::trim(value);
        next=p1+1;
    }
    return p1!=std::wstring::npos;
}
bool GetHTML(const std::string& url,std::wstring& header,std::wstring& hmtl) {
    std::wstring wurl = std::wstring(url.begin(),url.end());
    bool ret=false;
    try {
        WinHttpClient client(wurl.c_str());
        std::string url_protocol=url.substr(0,5);
        std::transform(url_protocol.begin(), url_protocol.end(), url_protocol.begin(), (int (*)(int))std::toupper);
        if(url_protocol=="HTTPS")    client.SetRequireValidSslCertificates(false);
        client.SetUserAgent(L"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
        if(client.SendHttpRequest()) {
            header = client.GetResponseHeader();
            hmtl = client.GetResponseContent();
            ret=true;
        }
    }catch(...) {
        header=L"Error";
        hmtl=L"";
    }
    return ret;
}
int main() {
    std::string url = "http://www.google.fr";
    std::wstring header,html;
    GetHTML(url,header,html));
}
```

Comment: code with no explanation is a bad idea, can you explain this?