# Web scraper for C++ similar to Perl's WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: c++, http, screen-scraping

I would like to know if there is a web-scraping library/API for C++ similar to Perl's WWW::Mechanize?  I'm not only looking for HTML parsing itself, but also support for stateful HTTP browsing, submission of Web forms, and maintaining and using cookies, for example to make a Web bot.

Comment: This is your seventh question, but you haven't accepted a single answer. You should really do something about that.

Comment: I didn't know I was supposed to. Although, sometimes my questions get answered and sometimes they don't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810845/how-do-i-automatically-complete-a-php-form-using-c

Comment: @user553702 There are certainly answers that do answer your questions (I just had a quick look through them). So if they do, you should definitely accept them. If you are unsatisfied, you should either comment on them, or edit your question (to specify more clearly why they don't).

Comment: Have you checked out cppnetlib ? http://cpp-netlib.github.com/

Comment: duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834768/options-for-web-scraping-c-version-only

Answer (score 2):

For web automation the bottleneck is I/O rather than CPU, which means it doesn't make sense to use a language like C++. Most of these kind of libraries are developed with higher level languages like Perl, Python, etc.

You can [use Perl in a C++ program](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch21_04.htm) so just use the original Perl library.

Comment: "the bottleneck is I/O rather than CPU, which means it doesn't make sense to use a language like C++" C++ is only used where CPU is the limiting factor?